# How to fix decimal error after the dot on Beecrowd platform for calculating percentages?

Tags: c, c99

For some reason when I put this code into the "Beecrowd" platform it shows as an error when generating decimals after the dot

```
#include <stdio.h>

double pct_cobaias(int x, int y);

int main() {
    
    int contador, cobaia;
    char tipo;
    int soma_cobaia, soma_coelho, soma_rato, soma_sapo;
    double pct_coelho, pct_rato, pct_sapo;

    scanf("%d", &contador);

    soma_cobaia = 0;
    soma_coelho = 0;
    soma_rato = 0;
    soma_sapo =  0;

    while (contador > 0)
    {
        scanf("%d %c", &cobaia, &tipo);

        if (cobaia >= 1 && cobaia <= 15)
        {
            if (tipo == 'C' || tipo == 'R' || tipo == 'S')
            {
                soma_cobaia += cobaia;

                if (tipo == 'C')
                {
                    soma_coelho += cobaia;
                }

                if (tipo == 'R')
                {
                    soma_rato += cobaia;
                }

                if (tipo == 'S')
                {
                    soma_sapo += cobaia;
                }
            }
        }

        contador--;
    }

    pct_coelho = pct_cobaias(soma_coelho, soma_cobaia);
    pct_rato = pct_cobaias(soma_rato, soma_cobaia);
    pct_sapo = pct_cobaias(soma_sapo, soma_cobaia);

    printf("Total: %d cobaias\n", soma_cobaia);

    printf("Total de coelhos: %d\n", soma_coelho);
    printf("Total de ratos: %d\n", soma_rato);
    printf("Total de sapos: %d\n", soma_sapo);

    printf("Percental de coelhos: %.2lf %\n", pct_coelho);
    printf("Percental de ratos: %.2lf %\n", pct_rato);
    printf("Percental de sapos: %.2lf %\n", pct_sapo);

    return 0;
}

double pct_cobaias(int x, int y) {

    double pct;

    pct = (x * 100) / y;

    return pct;
}
```

I would like the result in percent:

```
Percentual de coelhos: 32.62 %
Percentual de ratos: 33.48 %
...
```

I already changed from `float` to `double` and it still doesn't work

Comment: `(x*100)/y` performs integer math, *before* conversion to a double during assignment. Force floating point arithmetic: `x * 100.0 / y`.

Comment: thanks, it worked great, sometimes small errors go unnoticed xD

Answer (score 1):

You compute the percentage with `pct = (x * 100) / y;` but `x` and `y` have type `int` so the compiler uses integer arithmetics and the result is an integer.  You can fix this problem by writing:

```
   pct = (x * 100.0) / y;
```

Also note that you must use `%%` in the `printf` format string to output a `%` character.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int contador, cobaia;
    char tipo;
    double pct_coelho, pct_rato, pct_sapo;

    int soma_cobaia = 0;
    int soma_coelho = 0;
    int soma_rato = 0;
    int soma_sapo =  0;

    if (scanf("%d", &contador) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (contador > 0) {

        if (scanf("%d %c", &cobaia, &tipo) != 2)
            break;

        if (cobaia >= 1 && cobaia <= 15) {
            switch (tipo) {
              case 'C':
                soma_coelho += cobaia;
                soma_cobaia += cobaia;
                break;
              case 'R':
                soma_rato += cobaia;
                soma_cobaia += cobaia;
                break;
              case 'S':
                soma_sapo += cobaia;
                soma_cobaia += cobaia;
                break;
              default:
                printf("unknown product type\n");
                break;
            }
        } else {
            printf("invalid amount: %d\n", cobaia);
        }
        contador--;
    }

    pct_coelho = soma_coelho * 100.0 / soma_cobaia;
    pct_rato = soma_rato * 100.0 / soma_cobaia;
    pct_sapo = soma_sapo * 100.0 / soma_cobaia;

    printf("Total: %d cobaias\n", soma_cobaia);

    printf("Total de coelhos: %d\n", soma_coelho);
    printf("Total de ratos: %d\n", soma_rato);
    printf("Total de sapos: %d\n", soma_sapo);

    printf("Percental de coelhos: %.2f %%\n", pct_coelho);
    printf("Percental de ratos: %.2f %%\n", pct_rato);
    printf("Percental de sapos: %.2f %%\n", pct_sapo);

    return 0;
}
```